# Flipping a mosaic plot in R

Tags: r, mosaic-plot

I have a mosaic plot that looks like
[image: this]

but I need to show the proportions of Countries relative to roles, i.e. flip the chart. Is it possible to do without transposing the table?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the argument `split` determining the split *order* of the variables and `dir` for the split *direction* (horizontal vs. vertical). For example, both of these split in `Roles` first and then show the conditional proportions of `Countries` given `Roles` (either horizontally or vertically):

```
tab <- structure(c(12, 14, 23, 12, 26, 13), .Dim = c(3L, 2L),
  .Dimnames = structure(list(
    Countries = c("American", "European", "Japanese"),
    Roles = c("student", "staff")),
  .Names = c("Countries", "Roles")), class = "table")
mosaicplot(tab, sort = 2:1, dir = c("h", "v"))
mosaicplot(tab, sort = 2:1, dir = c("v", "h"))
```

[image: mosaic]

Note that the `mosaic()` function in package `vcd` also comes with a formula-based interface and more display options.